# How to implicitly wrap a value that can be null or an array into an Scala Option

Tags: scala, null, implicit-conversion, implicit

I have this Java class in a Jar file included as a dependency of an Scala program (like the Axis jar):

```
class MyClass {
    private String[] someStrings;
    public String[] getSomeStrings() { return someStrings; }
}
```

In my Scala program I have a Java API that return an instance of MyClass instance of MyClass to my program in Scala:

```
val myInstance = JavaAPI.getInstanceOfMyClass()
```

Then I try to use the **someStrings** array in my Scala program but it's **null** (let say that it wasn't properly initialized)

```
for(str <- myInstance.getSomeStrings()) ...
```

So this throws a **NullPointerException**.

I've found that in order to use it in the for comprehension I can wrap it into an Option so that it handles the NPE properly.

```
for(str <- Option[Array[String]](myInstance.getSomeStrings).getOrElse(Array[String]())
```

But that doesn't look OK to me.

Is there a way to create like an implicit method that takes that value even if it's null and wrap it into the Option, like:

```
implicit def wrapNull(a: Null): Option[Nothing] = None
implicit def wrapArray(a: Array[String]): Option[Array[String]] = Some(a)
```

So that when I do:

```
for(str <- myInstance.getSomeStrings())
```

I don't get the **NPE**

Comment: You should have specified the "chained nullable partial results" requirement in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your version with `getOrElse` is that bad (you can make it a little shorter by removing the `[Array[String]]` after `Option`, since that can be inferred). If you want something even more concise, the following works:

```
for (str <- Option(myInstance.getSomeStrings).flatten) ...
```

You could also use the fact that `Option` has a `foreach`:

```
for {
  strings <- Option(myInstance.getSomeStrings)
  str <- strings
} ...
```

Note that you can't use `yield` here, for the reason that drexin highlights in a comment below.

Or you could [pimp](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) `MyClass`:

```
implicit def withNullWrapper(c: MyClass) = new {
  def getSomeStringsOrNot() = Option(c.getSomeStrings).getOrElse(Array[String]())
}

for (str <- myInstance.getSomeStringsOrNot) ...
```

Comment: Your flatMap example will not work, because it does not follow the monad laws. strings is an Array[String] and therefore flatMap can't be used here.

Comment: You're right—but the same `for`-comprehension syntax will work if you don't use `yield`.

Comment: Yes, because it will be translated to a nested `foreach`. But then you rely on side effects which should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

edit:

A `map`as well as a `flatMap` always have to return the same type, on which they are called. If you have a List, you will always get a List back from `map`. The same is true for an Option. If you try to mix 2 types in a flatMap, this will most likely not work. What should

```
Some(Array(1,2)).flatMap { x => 
  x.map { _ * 2 }
}
```

return? Some(2,4) is not possible. So you get a type error. For this reason you have to do a nested `map { map }` instead of `flatMap { map }`.

In your case it would work like this:

```
case class A(b: B)
case class B(c: String)

val result = for(as <- Option(Array(A(B("foo")), A(B("bar"))))) yield {
  for(a <- as; b <- Option(a.b); c <- Option(b.c)) yield {
    c
  }
}
```

The first `for` takes an `Option[Array[A]]` and returns an `Option[Array[String]]`. The nested for takes an `Array[A]` and returns an `Array[String]`. They both satisfy the monad laws. At the end you can safely call `getOrElse` on `result` to unwrap the value if you want to.

original:

You could just do

```
val result = Option(myInstance.getSomeStrings).map { x =>
  x.map { y =>
    // do stuff with strings
  }
}
```

or

```
val result = for(x <- Option(myInstance.getSomeStrings)) yield {
  x.map { y =>
    // do stuff with strings
  }
}
```

You don't need to write the types because of the type inference and you don't need `getOrElse`, because the map will not be executed for `None`. You can then simply do a `getOrElse` on result, if you need to unwrap the value.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I should explained my self better. The problem is when you have "nested?" assignments? in the for like for(a <- As; b <- a.b; c <- b.c). How is this done with the option? a, b and c can be null.  for(a <- Option(As); b <- Option(a.flatten).get.b and so on?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Simple rule: where there's a `null`, make it an `Option`. So:

```
for {
  array <- Option(myInstance.getSomeStrings)
  element <- array
  thingy <- Option(element.method)
} yield thingy
```

Only that won't work. Because of the `array`, it will return multiple elements, but because the first generator is an `Option`, it will return an `Option`. These two elements are adverse: you can't return an `Option` of multiple elements.

The simplest alternative to fix the problem is to convert the `Option` into an iterator or a collection (according to your taste). Like this:

```
for {
  array <- Option(myInstance.getSomeStrings).toSeq
  element <- array
  thingy <- Option(element.method)
} yield thingy
```

Note that the second `Option` need not be touched: the one that caused the problem was the one as the first generator. `Option` anywhere other than the first generator is not a problem.